# Open scrollable pdf after button tapped Swift

Tags: swift, pdf, swift5, scrollable

I was wondering if that was possible? I want my users to tap on a button, e.g., "Find out more"

```
let findOutMoreButton: UIButton = {
let button = UIButton()
button.setTitle("Find out more", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
return button
}()

@objc func handleTapped() {
//This will bring the user to the scrollable .pdf via pushViewController
}
```

So I have this button and when the user taps it, to find out more, a pushViewController will bring them to a scrollable pdf file, with text information. Is that possible?
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have pdf file inside project or already downloaded, then you can use `QLPreviewController`. It is native controller from iOS to show documents.

Here is a good articles on how to implement it properly.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/10447506-quicklook-previews-for-ios-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.view.addSubview(pdfView)
        
        pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        
        pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        
        pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        
        pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        
        guard let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "your_file_name", withExtension: "pdf") else { return }
        
        if let doc = PDFDocument(url: fileURL) {
            pdfView.document = doc
        }
```

Also, make sure the file is not in the Assets.xcassets folder